# Frequency Distriution - Python - Importing From CSV

Tags: python, csv, import, multiple-columns

I am trying to import a csv file, this file has two columns: `Bachelor's` and `Master's`. I want to assign the majors that are for each to a string that represents both the student level (Bachelors or Masters) and the major (e.g. Business).

This CSV file is written in the form:

```
Bachelor's  Master's

SBS         O
H           O
H           0
H           O
```

...             ...

This is made from two separate columns.
I have the following code that I have been using:

```
Major_Proper = ['Business', 'Computer Sciences and 
Engineering','Education','Humanities','Natural Sciences and 
Mathematics','Other']

Degree = {"Bachelor's":['B','CSE','E','H','NSM','O'],"Master's":['B','CSE','E','H','NSM','O']}

Major = ['B','CSE','E','H','NSM','O']
b_b = m_b = []
b_cse = m_cse = []
b_e = m_e = []
b_nsm = m_nsm = []
b_sbs = n_nsm = []
b_o = m_o = []
bach = []
mast = []

with open('Majors.csv') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n',"")
    df = pd.read_csv('Majors.csv', header=None,  names=["Bachelor's", "Master's"])

    for x in range(0,len(bach)):
        if x == Major[0]:
            b_b.append(x)
        if x == Major[1]:
            b_cse.append(x)
        if x == Major[2]:
            b_e.append(x)            
        if x == Major[3]:
            b_nsm.append(x)
        if x == Major[4]:
            b_sbs.append(x)
        if x == Major[5]:
            b_o.append(x)

    for x in range(0,len(mast)):
        if x == Major[0]:
            m_b.append(x)
        if x == Major[1]:
            m_cse.append(x)
        if x == Major[2]:
            m_e.append(x)            
        if x == Major[3]:
            m_nsm.append(x)
        if x == Major[4]:
            m_sbs.append(x)
        if x == Major[5]:
            m_o.append(x)

print(df)
print(len(bach),len(mast))
```

My guess though is that the data is spitting out one long line, as seen below:

```
                         Bachelor's  Master's

Bachelor's Master's NaN         NaN       NaN
SBS        O        NaN         NaN       NaN
H          O        NaN         NaN       NaN
           B        NaN         NaN       NaN
           O        NaN         NaN       NaN
```

...

[101 rows x 2 columns]
2 2
Rows.
As you can see, some values were skipped. And three other columns were made.
As well, there should be only 100 rows, since the first row was the header. And the length of `bach` (Bachelor's) and `mast` (Master's) should have both been 100, not 2.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, nothing is happening when you open the file as `f`. I'm guessing this is some vestigial code from an earlier attempt. Also, if your CSV file already has the header titles you want, then you can omit the `header=None,  names=["Bachelor's", "Master's"]` argument on read_csv. Thirdly, `SBS` is missing from your Degree lists.

I don't know what you're doing in your for loops, since `bach` and `mast` are both empty lists and nothing should be evaluated here.

Maybe you can explain what you're trying to get from your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not very clear to me what you want to achieve (you should tidy up your code ;)

You are removing all newline-characters and creating one long row in your first line (`data=f.read().replace('\n','')`, which - I guess -  is meant to remove empty lines. Use s.th. like `x.replace('\n\n','\n')` instead. But in the end you aren't actually using `data` and going on with `pd.read_csv()`.

If you decide to use `data` you could do s.th. like

```
 data = f.read().replace('\n\n','\n')
 bach=[re.split(' ',x)[0] for x in re.split('\n',data)]
 mast=[re.split(' ',x)[1] for x in re.split('\n',data)]
```

to get a list of each the bachelor's and master's columns.

Also your `for x in range(len(mast)):` iteration is false: you are iterating through a list of integers, returned by `range()` (look what happens with `print(range(5))`).
What you want to do is `for x in mast:` as `mast` already is a list (same for `bach`).

What about simply using `if x=='B':` ? You would get rid of that unwieldy `list Major`. I would also replace the if-cascade with

```
if x=='B':
  b_b.append(x)
elif x=='CSE':
  b_cse.append(x)
etc...
```